# Having issues with my onClick on a registration form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, jsx

New to react so I apologize if the solution obvious. Working on a registration form that should create a new account on submit using ajax. I know that I'm supposed to use onChange to gather the information is submitted. After seeing a number of examples I am still unable to get my code to work.

I know that the ajax call for POST works because I put in information myself on vscode to test if on submit it will create which it did. I am having issues with the transition from onChange to my submit form. Hope that was clear. Thank you

I've tried creating a onChange function for my registration template. I am unable to get the results that I've been hoping for

```
class Form extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      payload: {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        passwordConfirm: ""
      }
      };
      }

      handleChange = event => {
      let name = event.target.name;
      let value = event.target.value;
      this.setState({
      [name]: value,
      [name]: value,
      [name]: value,
      [name]: value,
      [name]: value
      });
      };

    onClickHandler = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let payload = this.state;
    console.log(payload);
    debugger;

    registerService
      .register(payload)
      .then(this.onActionSuccess)
      .catch(this.onActionError);
   };

   onActionSuccess = response => {
    console.log(response);
   };

    onActionError = errResponse => {
    console.log(errResponse);
    };

    <!-- -->

    render() {
    return (
      <main role="main">
        <div className="container">
          <h1 id="title" align="center">
            Register User
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="col-sm-4 col-sm offset-4">
            <form className="form">
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="this.state.firstName">First Name</label>
                <input
                  placeholder="First Name"
                  type="text"
                  id="this.state.firstName"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="firstName"
                  value={this.state.firstName}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="this.state.lastName">Last Name</label>
                <input
                  placeholder="last Name"
                  type="text"
                  id="this.state. lastName"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.lastName}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="register-email">Email</label>
                  <input
                    placeholder="Enter Email"
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="register-email"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="register-password">Password</label>
                <input
                  placeholder="Password"
                  type="password"
                  id="register-password"
                  `enter code here`className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="register-passwordConfirm">
                  Confirm Password
                </label>
                <input
                  placeholder="Confirm Password"
                  type="password"
                  id="register-passwordConfirm"
                  className="form-control"
                  value={this.state.passwordConfirm}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              </div>
              <button onClick={this.onClickHandler} className="btn btn- 
              primary">
                Submit Form
              </button>
```

I am expecting to create a new profile when clicking submit via POST ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handleChange` function should be

```
      handleChange = event => {
      let { name, value } = event.target;

      this.setState({
            [name]: value,
      });
      };
```

You always call your `handleChange` once at a time. Every time you change something on the input, the function gets different `name` and different `value`, which is suffice to add/update the your state.

And I noticed that you also have `payload` object in state. Modify the state like

```
this.state = {
   firstname: '',
   ....
}
```

If you really want to use like

```
 this.state = {
        payload: {
           firstName: '',
           ....
           }
       };
```

Your `onChange` function should look like,

```
      handleChange = event => {
      let { name, value } = event.target;

      this.setState({
            payload: {
               ...this.state.payload, // don't forget to copy all the other values
               [name]: value,
            }
      });
      };
```

Comment: It worked! thank you very much. Could you explain to me what "...this.state.payload" represents? specially the "..." part of it. Would like to understand it more, thank you

Comment: Please see the `Javascript rest operator` for object. This is the new syntax, but you can also use `Object.assign()` syntax if you prefer that one. see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: I really appreciate the help. With Object.assign would it then turn into object.assign(this.state.payload) [name]:value,

Comment: `Object.assign(this.state.payload, { [name]: value})`.  Your `target` and `source` both has to be an `object`.